# Form of a function from its series

Tags: complex-analysis

Can you please help me to understand why if $\frac{1}{\big(1 - \overline{\lambda}f(z)\big)^n} = \sum_{r=1}^n \frac{c_r}{\big(1 - \overline{\lambda}z\big)^r}$ , then $f(z)$ is of the form $f(z) = a + bz$, a,b are complex numbers? Where $f(z)$ analytic and $\lambda \in \mathbb{D} - \{0\}$, $\mathbb{D}$ is the open unit disk.

Comment: What is $\mathbb{D}?$

Comment: getting rid of denominators, you have $Q(z)g(z)=(1 - \overline{\lambda}z\big)^n$ for some polynomial $Q$ of degree at most $n-1$ where $g(z)=(1 - \overline{\lambda}f(z))^n$; hence $g$ is a rational function but being an $n$th power, and since $Q$ has degree at most $n-1$ it follows that $Q$ must be a constant $c$ and $c(1 - \overline{\lambda}f(z))^n=(1 - \overline{\lambda}z\big)^n$ etc

Comment: let $r^*$ be the minimum index $r$ such that $c_r \neq 0$ and apply dog-on-a-leash to argue that for $\vert z\vert $ large enough the Right Hand Side has degree (winding number around zero) $=-r^*\neq 0$ but the Left Hand Side's degree is a multiple of $n\implies r^*=n\implies \Big(\frac{1-\bar \lambda f(z)}{1-\bar \lambda z}\Big)^n$ is constant hence $\frac{1-\bar \lambda f(z)}{1-\bar \lambda z}$ takes on at most $n$ values thus is constant by continuity/connectedness. Now re-arrange terms.